# Or Condition Not Working Proprelly?

Tags: android

im trying to Achieve a simple result from a Simple looking condition, but no idea why doesnt it work when every thing looks ok !

```
   public static String getMIME(File file){

     String result=null;
     String type = null;
     String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file.getAbsolutePath());
     if (extension != null) {
         MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
         type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
         if(type!=null){ 
             final String SplittedType=(type.split("\\/"))[0];
             System.out.println("Splittedtype: "+SplittedType);
             Log.i("MIME",type);
             if(!SplittedType.equals("image") || !SplittedType.equals("video") ){
                result = "Unknown";
            }else{
                result = SplittedType;
            }

         }else{
             result = "Unknown";
         }

     }
     System.out.println("Result : "+result);
     return result;

  }
```

Logcat Shows Right values,but Result is always "Unknown" while the SplittedType is either image or video, only thing i can think of is the OR Condition is Not Wokring !

Comment: You can be sure you have not discovered such a major bug in Java/Android and, `!=` should not be used for `String`.

Comment: have you commented on the right post ? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use an AND condition (&&).

```
if(!SplittedType.equals("image") && !SplittedType.equals("video") ){
    result = "Unknown";
} else {
    result = SplittedType;
}
```

Only if the type is not "image" AND not "video", then you it's unknown. If the type is "image" OR "video", then it is NOT "Unknown".

Comment: yes, some times most simple thing get too complicates, changed it like this and its fine :   if(SplittedType.equals("image")  || SplittedType.equals ("video")) { result = SplittedType